# Why is looping over DataFrame rows based on a condition only giving correct result for first row? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am looping over the rows of a DataFrame, in which each row contains a string in 'column_A' and a tuple in 'column_B'. If the tuple in 'column_B' meets a certain condition, an operation is performed on the string in 'column_A' and the result is to be stored as a string in 'column_C'. If the condition is not met, nothing is to be stored in 'column_C'. This is my DataFrame:

```
 **column_A                 column_B     column_C**         
0  This is a string.        [A, B, C]    
1  And this a string.       [A, B, D]    
2  Yet another string.      [A, B, C]    
3  For the love of strings. [A, B, C]
```

My script looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_pickle('dataframe.pkl')

condition = [('A', 'B', 'C')]

def operation(j):
    # some operations here
    return i

df_list = []
for index, row in a.iterrows(): 
    b = tuple(row['column_B']) 
    if b in condition: 
        lst = []
        c = a['column_A'].apply(operation) # run function 'operation' above 
        lst.append(c) 
        df = pd.DataFrame([lst]) # Here things go wrong. Only first string from column_A is added
        df_list.append(df)

df = pd.concat(df_list)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
a.insert(3, 'Column_C', df)
```

Based on the script, I expect to get my desired result:

```
 **column_A                 column_B     column_C**         
0  This is a string.        [A, B, C]    This is a string!
1  And this a string.       [A, B, D]    
2  Yet another string.      [A, B, C]    Yet another string!
3  For the love of strings. [A, B, C]    For the love of strings!
```

However, I get the following result:

```
 **column_A                 column_B     column_C**         
0  This is a string.        [A, B, C]    0  This is a string!
1  And this a string.       [A, B, D]    0  This is a string!
2  Yet another string.      [A, B, C]    0  This is a string!
3  For the love of strings. [A, B, C]    0  This is a string!
```

It is very unclear to me why each string is preceded by a '0' and why the processed version of only the first string appears - in every row. Any suggestions why this happens and how to change the script to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option versus iterating rows is to use `pd.DataFrame.apply`.

This avoids the expensive process you have of creating a dataframe for each row and concatenating them.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_A': ['This is a string.', 'And this a string.',
                                'Yet another string.', 'For the love of strings.'],
                   'column_B': [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D'],
                               ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]})

def func(row):
    if row['column_B'] in [['A', 'B', 'C']]:
        return row['column_A']
    else:
        return ''

df['column_C'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)

#                    column_A   column_B                  column_C
# 0         This is a string.  [A, B, C]         This is a string.
# 1        And this a string.  [A, B, D]                          
# 2       Yet another string.  [A, B, C]       Yet another string.
# 3  For the love of strings.  [A, B, C]  For the love of strings.
```

Comment: Oh yes, that is much simpler! When I run this it works. But when I plug this in my script, column_C remains empty - even tough some tuples in column_B meet the condition.

Comment: That's strange. My example as above works fine. I'd advise you update your question with new logic to demonstrate the problem. Most likely something is wrong with either your data or your function on `column_A`.

Comment: It works. To make the condition check work, had to convert column_B to tuples using: b = tuple(row['column_B']) and then if b in temp1: Then it works. Thanks!